# is there any reason not to use the highest gradle version available in android studio?

Tags: android, gradle

the google play console advised me to use the debugSymbolLevel option, but it seems that requires a higher gradle plugin version(4.1). Currently my Android Gradle Plugin Version is 3.5.4 and my Gradle Version 5.6.4

I know very little about gradle. Is there any reason i shouldn't just select the highest versions for both? If yes which ones should i use?
Android Gradle Plugin Version offers options up to 7.3.1
Gradle Version upt to '8.0-milestone2'

Answer (score 0):

Since the two versions span a lot, there might be a lot of breaking changes for your project. I suggest you doing some backup, trying to choose a stable version of it (7.x) and running the project. Good luck.